# EF 5.0 WinForms Add New Row in Bound DataGridView

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, data-binding

I've set up a bound dgv to entity using dbcontext.  Works fine.  The rows are displayed in the dgv and I can modify cells and update using SaveChanges.  However, if I attempt to add a new row in the dgv it doesn't get saved.  If the dgv is bound to the entity shouldn't the new row get added automatically or do I have to do something to add it?  What?  Please provide example code.  I'm going to try deleting from the dgv next.  Will I have a similar problem?  How might I get that to work?  I scoured the internet for examples but they stop at binding the enitities and don't include addition or deletions.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a couple of links with a similar problem one of which is:

[DataGridView AllowUserToAddRow property doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799661/datagridview-allowusertoaddrow-property-doesnt-work)

It seems that using .ToList messes up the binding.  In my case I was using MyContext.MyTable.Local.ToList as the source.  When I removed the .ToList everything works perfectly.  Perhaps someone can tell us in more detail why this works???

Thanks to those of you that found this first.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for .NET Framework 4

I have tried Removing the .ToList() but then I simply get no results.

So my workaround was:

For deletes:
On the datagridview UserDeletingRow Event

```
// Get deleted entity:
myEntityType currentEntity = (myEntityType)BindingSource[e.Row.Index];

// Delete directly from context
context.myEntityType.Remove(currentEntity);
```

For inserts:
On the save button I loop through the BindingSource and check if any enitity has an ID == 0 and then ADD each of those with context.MyEntityType.Add(currentEntity);