# Adding/Removing rows in DataGridView with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I'm creating a simple desktop app (.NET 4.5) for a group of windows users. I'm looking at using Entity Framework (6). The design was database first.

```
CREATE TABLE [CommodityCombo](
    Recid INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [CommodityComboMember] (
    Commodity VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ComboId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES CommodityCombo(Recid)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

So that's the SQL for two of the tables. The concept was a pair of master/detail datagridviews. The master would be for adding/removing CommodityCombos and the detail for adding/removing members.

So then in the form load event handler I have ...

```
try
{
    db = new MyEntities();
    var combos = (from c in db.CommodityCombos
                  select c);
    //this.dataGridView1.DataSource = combos;
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = db.CommodityCombos.ToList();
}
catch (Exception e1)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e1.Message);
}
```

Now I was thinking it would pretty simple if the datagridview had the regular add/remove capability. i.e. you could highlight a row and press [Delete] or add information in the bottom blank row. But this doesn't seem to work. The records come in, but the "natural" add/delete doesn't work.

Now I found this article... 
[DataGridView AllowUserToAddRow property doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799661/datagridview-allowusertoaddrow-property-doesnt-work)

And the accepted answer suggests that the thing to do is to pass the query object.

However, this creates an exception... and there's this article that corresponds...
[Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938371/data-binding-directly-to-a-store-query-dbset-dbquery-dbsqlquery-is-not-suppo)
... which basically says I have to use object.toList().

Admittedly, I noticed that the first article's accepted answer hints at using a binding source, but it's missing some of the detail that goes into presenting the results of the query as a binding source while preserving the add/remove capability and simultaneously not throwing an exception.

Can someone shed more light on this? Or maybe point me in the direction of a better resource? Or should I just can the idea and create [New] and [Delete] buttons to handle it manually?

Comment: [Entity Framework Databinding with WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx).  This step-by-step walkthrough shows how to bind POCO types to Window Forms (WinForms) controls in a “master-detail" form. The application uses Entity Framework to populate objects with data from the database, track changes, and persist data to the database.

Comment: Sweet, thanks! I'll check it out.