# An extra row in DataGridView(with CheckBox column) when using DataTables

Tags: c#, datagridview

As you can see [in this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/adding-checkbox-column-in-datagridview-in-C-Sharp-window-forms/) there are several ways to fill a DataGridView that contains a CheckBox Column with data. They are:

- Binding a List to a DataGridView having a bool property
- Binding a datatable to a DataGridView having a bool column
- Adding a checkbox column (DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn) to the DataGridView.

Ignoring the third one, there is a difference between the first two (and you can see it in the result screen in the tutorial).

When you use a List, you get what you want: A DataGridView with a column that has CheckBox columns

However if you use the second method (a datatable), you get a DataGridView with a column that has CheckBox columns *but with an extra empty row!*

You can see it in the Pic in the tutorial:
[image: The extra row]

Not only that but if you check on the empty row checkbox you get another empty row and that could go forever.

This is obviously undesirable behavior. So far I have been using Lists and they work ok but I would like to use dataTables to fill the DataGridView. Is there a way to avoid having this undersirable behavior and just get the exact rows?

Comment: This is a DGV property AllowUserToAddRows. simply turn it off! - And no, I doubt it has anything to do with what else you did, including adding that bool column.

Comment: @TaW so simple! Thanks!  The curious thing is that with Lists this does not happen!

Comment: Indeed! Loks like the reason is that DataTable is able to accept new rows but List isn't. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799661/datagridview-allowusertoaddrow-property-doesnt-work)