# Why should I use ToList() method with repeaters and EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working with an sql server database and entity framework (version 6).

Look at this code behind code:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private bdd1Entities bdd = new bdd1Entities();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Repeater1.DataSource = bdd.Personnes.ToList();
            Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

And here is the repeater source in aspx page:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Nom")  %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

It works fine but if I remove the ToList() function call in code behind, I got

> this exception:  System.NotSupportedException

I do not understand why. I just want to understand thanks

Comment: 1 millionth question with the tag c# :)

Comment: What is the actual exception message?

Comment: @CodeCaster Probably - Data binding directly to a store query is not supported.

Comment: @Andriy that looks plausible, accepted that duplicate. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Repeater control provides support for data binding to any object that implements the `System.Collections.IEnumerable` interface (such as a DataView,ArrayList, Hashtable etc), or the `IListSource` interface. In your case, there might not be any implicit conversation exist from either of aforementioned interface to your 'Personnes' instance. This is why you are required to convert it to `List` or cast it to source interface type.

Comment: Why EF objects does not implements System.Collections.IEnumerable ? Is there a way to change that ?

Comment: I presume, it might be returning IQueryable<T> and not IEnumerable<T>. You can check this while pointing cursor to your Personnes. Can you tell me what is the type of 'Personnes' when you place cursor ( while debug)

Comment: @Nair [IQueryable<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562(v=vs.110).aspx) implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: We don't know what the custom type return and I asked to submit more details. Additionally, If you look at one of EF thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674649/webforms-data-binding-with-ef-code-first-linq-query-error?noredirect=1&lq=1), similar type of issues are discussed where we expect these to work in general.